# Apache Flink average on sliding window

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I’m trying to calculate an average with a sliding window. Here’s the code I’m using. First of all I receive a series of events from a Kafka topic. I declared a watermark on the ‘data_fine’ attribute.

```
final TableDescriptor filteredPhasesDurationsTableDescriptor = TableDescriptor.forConnector("upsert-kafka")
       .schema(Schema.newBuilder()
             .column("id_fascicolo", DataTypes.BIGINT().notNull())
             .column("nrg", DataTypes.STRING())
             .column("giudice", DataTypes.STRING())
             .column("oggetto", DataTypes.STRING())
             .column("codice_oggetto", DataTypes.STRING())
             .column("ufficio", DataTypes.STRING())
             .column("sezione", DataTypes.STRING())
             .column("fase", DataTypes.STRING().notNull())
             .column("durata", DataTypes.BIGINT())
             .column("data_inizio", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3))
             .column("data_fine", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3))
             .watermark("data_fine", "data_fine - INTERVAL '5' SECOND")
             .primaryKey("id_fascicolo", "fase")
             .build())
       .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.TOPIC, List.of("sicid.processor.filtered-phases-durations"))
       .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.PROPS_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS, KAFKA_HOST)
       .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.KEY_FORMAT, "json")
       .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.VALUE_FORMAT, "json")
       .build();
tEnv.createTable("FilteredPhasesDurations_Kafka", filteredPhasesDurationsTableDescriptor);
Table filteredPhasesDurationsTable = tEnv.from("FilteredPhasesDurations_Kafka”);
```

After receiving the events I compute the average using a sliding window like this:

```
Table averageJudgeByPhase = filteredPhasesDurationsTable
       .window(Slide.over(lit(15).days())
             .every(lit(1).days())
             .on($("data_fine"))
             .as("w"))
       .groupBy(
             $("giudice"),
             $("fase"),
             $("w")
       )
       .select(
             $("giudice"),
             $("fase"),
             $("durata").avg().as("mediaMobileGiudicePerFase"),
             $("w").end().as("data_fine")
       );
averageJudgeByPhase.execute().print();
```

But I get no results.
These are some test events in the Kafka topic. The data_fine attribute has a span of more than 15 days so why the average is not computed?

```
+----+----------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| op |         id_fascicolo |                            nrg |                        giudice |                        oggetto |                 codice_oggetto |                        ufficio |                        sezione |                           fase |               durata |             data_inizio |               data_fine |
+----+----------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| +I |                    9 |                            301 |                      giudice01 |                     Usucapione |                         131002 |                      Benevento |                             01 |              FASE_INTRODUTTIVA |                   14 | 2023-04-16 02:00:00.000 | 2023-04-30 02:00:00.000 |
| +I |                   10 |                            302 |                      giudice01 |                     Usucapione |                         131002 |                      Benevento |                             01 |              FASE_INTRODUTTIVA |                   15 | 2023-04-30 02:00:00.000 | 2023-05-15 02:00:00.000 |
| +I |                    8 |                            300 |                      giudice01 |                     Usucapione |                         131002 |                      Benevento |                             01 |              FASE_INTRODUTTIVA |                   14 | 2023-04-01 02:00:00.000 | 2023-04-15 02:00:00.000 |
```

Thanks,
Eugenio

Comment: If your source parallelism is greater than the number of partitions in your Kafka topic, or you have idle partitions, then you might be dealing with the idle source issue.  See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/config/#table-exec-source-idle-timeout

Comment: Thank you. After setting table.exec.source.idle-timeout it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with lower window time size, It might be possible that flink waits for 15 days to generate a result, You can try by reducing window timer to 1 or 2 minutes maybe

Comment: Ok but since I defined the window on the event time shouldn’t the time flow based on the data_fine attribute?

Comment: For the test, you can try manipulating data

Answer (score 0):

Your test data doesn't contain events that are past the 15 days of your sliding window. It needs events past those 15 days to being able to determine that the 15 days have passed and that the window can be closed.

Comment: But the first event has 'data_fine' 2023-04-30 and the second event 2023-05-15. Is it not enough? Shouldn't the window be closed?

Comment: Given that there's no event after 2023-05-15, Flink currently thinks that it's exactly 2023-05-15. There could be another event coming in with exactly the same timestamp. Given that this is still in the window, there's nothing for Flink to close.

Comment: OK I added some more events but nothing happens. It's like the watermark is never emitted.

Comment: You can check in the Flink UI what is the emitted watermark. It could also be that your parallelism is higher then the number of partitions, causing issues with idleness. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#idleness for more info